# Composite functions and their domains

Tags: calculus

I have a question regarding the domain of this function cube root/square root function.

$$\sqrt[3]{1-\sqrt{x}}$$

So, according to the answer key, it is $0 \le x \le 1$, but I don't understand why this is so because isn't the domain all real numbers that are above $0$? Since there is a square root, it would be $0 \le x$. So why is $x$ only allowed values between $0$ and $1$ inclusive?

Original functions were $$f(x) = \sqrt[3]{1-x}$$

and $$g(x) = \sqrt[2]{x}$$

The book wanted me to do $$f(g(x))$$.

Comment: Where is the cube root? To get a $\sqrt{A}$ or $\sqrt[3]{A}$ in $\LaTeX$, use "\sqrt{A}" and "\sqrt[3]{A}$ respectively.

Comment: The "3" was too big i guess, but it is a cube root enclosing a square root.

Comment: I'm doubtful, given the key answer, that it is a cube root.  I suspect it was three times an outer square root.  However I edited the LaTeX to make a cube root for you.

Comment: That is the correct function, is the answer key right or wrong on this :\...

Comment: Certainly there's a valid cube root for negative real numbers.  E.g. my calculator takes cube root of -1 and gets -1.

Comment: Indeed, which is why I am so confused...Originally this was two functions f of g and I combined them into one. The combining part was correct, but the domain they give is whacked.

Comment: The most logical explanation is a typo. $0\le x\le1$ is the domain of $\sqrt{1-\sqrt x}$ or $\sqrt[4]{1-\sqrt x}$ etc.

Comment: I see, so I assume it's all real numbers where x is greater than or equal to 0.

Comment: Or possibly there is something else about those two functions that was lost when you rewrote the expression. What were the functions?

Comment: I will write the original functions in original post

Comment: I see. OK, I'll go with the "typo" hypothesis then.